# Chrome Extension content script DOM not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

i have a trouble with content script.

When oi run it with breakpoint its work fine, but without breakpoint not working properly. $(this).html(a.farewell); not update DOM.

My manifest contain "run_at": "document_end"

```
$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            var a = "1";
            var rows = $("tr.row");

            rows.each(function (i) {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-bull-id");
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ getStorage: id }, function (response) {
                    a = response;
                    console.log(response.farewell);
                    $(this).html(a.farewell);
                });


               // this.innerHTML = a.test;

            });


            console.log("ready2!");
        });


    });
```

Comment: Did you try just removing *both* DOM ready handlers ?

Comment: can you please add your html

Comment: adeneo, yes i try remove both handlers - no effect;

Comment: I am actually not sure what $(this) inside sendMessage callback is. If you are trying to access the individual raw, I would assign $(this) to variable outside that callback.

Comment: What i-- says. Also, in general it could be that the elements you are looking for (tr.row) are loaded later with ajax thus you might need to SetTimeout until you find some.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**i,**
I am actually not sure what $(this) inside sendMessage callback is. If you are trying to access the individual raw, I would assign $(this) to variable outside that callback.

By this comment help me, because it was mistake in $(this), "this" is reference to  message but not to element.

Comment: Can you explain why you copied a comment by someone else verbatim as an answer? If it helped you, show how. As is, this is a very poor answer.